# How to insert date/time stamp in PSPad?

Tags: text-editors, pspad

Does anyone know if there is a hotkey in [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) to insert a time stamp in this format:

2009-07-27 23:47:33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it:

- Edit | Date/Time Dialog, change it, be sure to click "Replace"
- then ALT-D

Comment: Thanks, actually it exists in an obvious location and is extremely easy to use.